# Android Studio: Ignoring conflict for the value

Tags: java, android-studio

When i try to create a new Basic Activity in my project I get this error. Maybe someone knows what could be wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z095q.png

Comment: Please post any information which can give insight to what the error is. The best way would be to post the stacktrace here. This would help people to answer your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact fix to this error but in the AndroidManifest.xml file you can change these settings for your app.

Seems like you've got some conflict between your application theme and your new activity theme

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

This theme hides the action bar in your app